Not able to get proper Data in the excel file created using ExcelJS package in NodeJS
so i trying to create a xlx file from the input and upload it to S3 bucket so
when i pass large data say 1000 rows I could see that only column headers are created in the file not the data but still the file size is around 100kb
but if i send small input i could see the rows getting created
any help is much appreciated
attaching the snippet of the code where i am trying to create xlsx file
 await Promise.all(
      payload.queryResults.map(async (queryResult: QueryResult) => {
        const { columnHeader, strId, queryName, data = [] } = queryResult; 

        try {
          // Process the Excel file
          const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
          const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet1');
         
          worksheet.addRow(columnHeader);
          // Add data rows only if `data` is a non-empty array
          if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
            data.forEach((row) => {
              const rowData = columnHeader.map(col => row[col] || '');
              worksheet.addRow(rowData);
            });
          }

          const filePath = filename.xlsx`;
          const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();

          await uploadFiletoS3(stagingBucket, filePath, Buffer.from(buffer));
          successfulQueries.push({ queryName, strId });
        } catch (uploadError) {
          failedQueries.push({ queryName, strId, error: uploadError.message });
          logger.error(`Error uploading file for query: ${queryName} for store: ${strId}`, { error: uploadError });
        }
      })
    );


